# Behaviour of 2 inline functions calling each other in C

Tags: c, gcc, inline

I am in the process of trying to learn C's more advanced aspects and wrote this when experimenting with the `__inline__` keyword:

```
#include <stdio.h>


void f(int);
void g(int);


__inline__ void f(int egg)
{
    printf("f %d\n", egg);
    g(egg);
}


__inline__ void g(int egg)
{
    printf("g %d\n", egg);
    f(egg);
}


int main()
{
    f(123);

    return 0;
}
```

I went to the GNU manuals and found that the `-Winline` compiler option warns when a function marked `__inline__` can't be substituted.

I was indeed expecting a warning, but I compiled this program with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Winline -o test test.c` and there were no warnings.

When I ran the program, it printed out the number a whole bunch of times before a segmentation fault, presumably due to the recursion limit being exceeded.

My question is, how does `gcc` behave in cases like that? If it does inline the functions, how does it know it hit a recursive call between two functions?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can look at the output of the compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/XZ_0NN (Spoiler: endless loop)

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the question, but didn't you just find out how gcc behaves in this situation?

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you use the standard keyword, `inline`, instead of the implementation extension, `__inline__`?

Comment: @mch Thank you for the resource, I had never come across that tool!

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I know the program successfully compiled, but I am not sure whether the functions are actually inlined or not. I will edit my question for clarification though :)

Comment: @SaucyGoat: why don't you simply use `inline`? Which gcc version is this?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Since I am specifying the ANSI standard, the keyword is `__inline__`. Your suggestion `inline` would work on C99, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Groo version 7.3.0

Comment: No, @SaucyGoat, `__inline__` has never been a keyword of any version of standard C, and it is unlikely to be a keyword of any future version, as its form is reserved for implementation use.  Do not confuse implementation extensions (such as `__inline__`) with standard features, and do not confuse studying the behavior of a specific implementation with studying the behavior required of all conforming implementations.

Comment: @JohnBollinger in the mouche. I misread the docs at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html and used `__inline__` for function definitions instead of headers. Feel free to elaborate an answer so I can mark the question as answered. Thank you!

Comment: @mch -- a loop does not explain the segfault in the OPs case?

Comment: @MFisherKDX The segfault was a note from OP, the questions were `My question is, how does gcc behave in cases like that? If it does inline the functions, how does it know it hit a recursive call between two functions?`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.4.0/gcc/Inline.html#Inline

> GCC does not inline any functions when not optimizing unless you specify the ‘always_inline’ attribute for the function

Since you are compiling without optimization, gcc does not even try to inline your functions, hence you do not get a warning that it wasn't done.

When I compile your code with `-O -Winline`, I get a warning as expected:

```
inline.c: In function ‘main’:
inline.c:8:17: warning: inlining failed in call to ‘f’: call is unlikely and code size would grow [-Winline]
 __inline__ void f(int egg)
                 ^
inline.c:24:5: note: called from here
     f(123);
     ^~~~~~
```

Comment: However, if you compile the code with `-O2 -Winline`, again you get no warning, and the code generated is an infinite loop with the bodies of both `f` and `g` inlined into `main` and no recursive calls.  This is because both the call from `f` to `g` and the call from `g` to `f` are [tail recursive](http://wiki.c2.com/?TailRecursion) so GCC can flatten out the recursion and successfully inline both functions.

Answer (score 2):

According to what I see in [goldbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/d-XSON) this case the compiler is smart enough to understand that that code is equivalent to a endless loop (see .L2 in the code below).
This optimization is possible when recursive functions are [**tail recursive**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization)

This has nothing to do with `__inline__`. In fact if you remove the `__inline__` keyword you get the same optimization and **also** the assembly code for `g` and `f`, which are never `call`ed.

```
     .LC0:
            .string "f %d\n"
    .LC1:
            .string "g %d\n"
    main:
            sub     rsp, 8
    .L2:
            mov     esi, 123
            mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
            xor     eax, eax
            call    printf
            mov     esi, 123
            mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
            xor     eax, eax
            call    printf
            jmp     .L2
```

The following compare the assembly generated by `gcc` with (on the right) and withtout (on the left) `__inline__` keyword for `g` and `f`. 
As you can see the `main` contains exactly the same code. The only difference is that you get additional code for `g` and `f`.[image]

Comment: It has to do with _inlining_, but not so much with the `inline` or `__inline__` keywords.  The compiler is allowed to inline functions even if you don't ask it to.

Comment: With -O3, I'm getting an identical (fully inlined) code inside `<main>:` both with and without  removing `__inline__` from the source.